# Intellij IDEA: Improving performance due to being incredibly slow at times

Tags: intellij-idea

I have these settings:

```
-server
-Xms2048m
-Xmx8096m
-XX:MaxPermSize=2048m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=2048m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=512
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd
```

Yes, they are maxed out.

I have also changed from 2500 to:

idea.max.intellisense.filesize=500

I am developing in a Java project which mostly works fine, although in some java classes it is slow at times, like when just editing a String.

However, today I am touching some html, css and javascript files and it is just going slower and slower.

The CPU level are not increasing considerably but just slow.

I am in debug mode most of the time, but i don't have auto build on save.

**What other parameters can I increase/decrease to get it run smoother?**

Right now it is not able to provide me with any help.

I have 24 GB ram and a I7-4810MQ so it's a pretty powerful laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this Jetbrains blog post](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2006/12/boosting-intellij-idea-performance-on-windows-systems/), you can often double the performance of IDEA by fixing various NTFS formatted disk related issues:

> If you are running a Windows machine with NTFS disks, there is a good chance to double the performance of IntelliJ IDEA by optimizing the MFT tables, disk folder structure and Windows paging file.
>
> We have used the Diskeeper, 2007 Pro Trial version tool to carry out the following procedure. You may of course, repeat this with your favorite defragmenter, provided it supports equivalent functionality.
>
> 1. Free about 25% space on the drive you are optimizing.
> 2. Turn off any real-time antivirus protection and reboot your system.
> 3. Defragment files.
> 4. Defragment MFT (Do a Frag Shield, if you are using Diskeeper). Note that this is quite lenghty process which also requires your
>      machine to reboot several times.
> 5. Defragment the folder structure (perform the Directory consolidation).
> 6. Defragment the Windows paging file.
>
> The above optimizations have positive impact not only on IntelliJ
>   IDEA, but on general system performance as well.

Comment: I am running on ubuntu and I have an ssd disc. I should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 1):

You could open VisualVM, YourKit or other profiler and see what exactly is slow.
Or just [report a performance problem](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/29983118-Reporting-performance-problems). 
VisualVM alone would tell you if the CPU is spending time with garbage collecting or normal stuff.

Large heap provides a considerable benefit only when garbage collection causes lags or eats too much CPU. Also if you enable a *Memory Indicator* by enabling  *Settings | Show Memory Indicator* you will see how much of heap is occupied and when GC clears it.

BTW you absolutely need an SSD.